# Jquery is not working on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, heroku, mean-stack

I have deployed my nodejs app on heroku. The app is deployed successfully. When I load the website, it loads fine. I checked the network calls and the Jquery is being loaded in the website, however the jQuery is not functional on my website. No alert box appears that is supposed to appear once jquery is ready. No logs appear that are supposed to appear when jquery is loaded. I have no idea why is this happening. Following is the code:

```
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script type = "text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <h1><%= title %></h1>
  <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>


  <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">


$(document).on("pageload",function(){
    alert("pageload event fired!");
});

$(document).on("ready",function(){
    alert("page ready event fired!");
    console.log("page ready");
});
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {console.log("ready");});
</script>
</head>
```

The app worked just fine and jquery worked great on local host.

Comment: Maybe you just need to correct some details, like the last tab, should be "script", not "head".

Comment: Other improvement, don't use "language='javascript'". Just "type='text/javascript'" is fine.

Comment: It's just a typo of the code I posted here.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure, you enclose all this between <html></html>, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your code's a mess. An extra closing tag for the head, no closing tag for the script. Change that final `</head> to </script>`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<head>
    <title>
        <%= title %>
    </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to
        <%= title %>
    </p>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("pageload", function() {
            alert("pageload event fired!");
        });

        $(document).on("ready", function() {
            alert("page ready event fired!");
            console.log("page ready");
        });
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("ready");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

> updated `</head>` to `</script>`
>
> removed language = "javascript"